# send an snmp trap in RHEL7.1

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, rhel7, snmptrapd

We are working on script to check a directory if the number of files in it goes above a certain threshold it sends an `snmptrap` to a `zabbix` server, the server is now running RHEL7.1, previously the script was running on solaris10 and the command was :

```
/usr/sfw/bin/snmptrap -v1 -c foo #ip 1.3.6.1.4.1.42 localhost 6 9 0 #oid s '#msg'
```

and now we couldn't find the equivalant command in RHEL7.1 .

Comment: did you try `yum provides */snmptrap` to find out what package provides the snmptrap command (probably net-snmp-utils)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the result for yum provides */snmptrap :

1:net-snmp-utils-5.7.2-24.el7.x86_64 : Network management utilities using SNMP,
                                     : from the NET-SNMP project
Repo        : local
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/snmptrap

but this /usr/bin/snmptrap does not exist in the system? any idea what to do?

Comment: yum will search *non installed* packages when you use provides. You should just be able to `yum install net-snmp-utils` to add the package to your system.